# .Net Assembly load issue if there is no direct reference to assembly member

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

Here is situation:
I have two projects. ConsoleApp and Class Library. Console app references class library.
There is Person class in Class library.

Following code returns null in type variable:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Type type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
.Select(a => a.GetType("LoadTest.Person", false)).Where(t => t != null).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

However if I add direct declaration, code is working well.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Person p = null;
   Type type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
.Select(a => a.GetType("LoadTest.Person", false)).Where(t => t != null).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

It is known problem. However is it any solution without declaration any assembly member?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The assembly isnt loaded. You have to load it first.

Comment: Does it mean that the only solution is to load it directly using CurrentDomain.Load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply:

```
  var personType = typeof(Person)
```

that will load the assembly and give you the type you want, but if you want to use the Assembly class for some reason, do this:

```
  var type = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Person)).GetType("LoadTest.Person");
```

or, if you do not know the type at runtime nor the dll filename but you can be sure that the dll is in the working directory you can do this:

```
  var type = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory).GetFiles("*.dll").Select(f => Assembly.LoadFile(f.FullName)).Select(assembly => assembly.GetType("LoadTest.Person")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I can't do it as I don't know type at runtime.

Comment: What do you have at runtime, a string of the fully qualified type name (LoadTest.Person)?

Answer (score 2):

the reason why it return null type variable is 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies doesn't contain the reference assembly you were added in the project. which is an isolated environment where application execute.

You need to load the class library into the AppDomain context for your assemblies.
Base on your example, Place this

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("LoadTest");
```

and you could get the list of assemblies during run-time using

```
Assembly[] assems = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Assembly.Load methods to load the assembly and then create type from it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the name of the assembly like:

```
GetType("LoadTest.Person, nameoftheassemblycontainingperson");
```

so let's say if your class person is contained in `LoadTest.dll`, you can write:

```
GetType("LoadTest.Person, LoadTest");
```

Don't forget to deploy it manually, since if you are removing the reference the assembly containing person will not be copied automatically in the place the working app.